# How to work ng-controller and result is not showing on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular JS. I wrote a bit of angular code.
i have defined controller code also.Can anybody tell me why i cannot get `scope` variable value?
Any thing i missed ?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
         <script src="angular.js"></script>
      </head> 
      <!--this above is external java script
          file my controller is not working, 
          what problem i am facing ?-->
    <body>
        <!-- the below is ng-controller -->
      <div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
         say hello to : <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
         <h1>  Hello, {{name}}! </h1>
     </div>
```

**Script:**

```
    <script>
         var HelloCtrl = function ($scope) {
            $scope.name = 'World';
         }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define your app and your controller like this :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("HelloCtrl", function ($scope) { 
    $scope.name = "world";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);`

Your `script` should look like:

```
<script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 var HelloCtrl = function ($scope) {
   $scope.name = 'World';
 }
</script>
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/HB7LU/13500/). Depends on angular version. :)

Comment: may be depends on angular version i think so @Sourabh

Comment: @Sourabh- I'm not a downvoter. Although your fiddle works it is a bad practice to pollute global (window) scope with a controller function. It is not the way Angular is intended. And besides on jsfiddle there exist a couple of AngularJS versions. So you don't need to provide external links for this framework :)

Comment: @KirillSlatin. You may be correct on the _bad practice_ thing. And I edited an existing fiddle, the _external link_ was already there so I chose not to remove it, simple :)